# How to turn off the voice assistant on Android 5.0 on Cruzr Robot

Tags: android, ros

I made a program to listen to a wakeup call, once happened it executes a function.
The voice assistant program overrides the listener, so my listener functions is not being executed due to the override by the voice assistance.

How to turn off the voice assistance so my listener function receives the wakeup call and get executed ?

Operating System: Android 5.0

Machine: Cruzer Robot.